# Assign functions value to variable jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this may seem a bit of a bazaar question, but I vaguely recall seeing this approach to setting a variable with jQuery some time ago.  I am aware that I could create a getter method which would do the same thing, but is there any way I can set my variable using this approach:

```
var type  = $('#select_type option:selected').text(),
    style = function() {
          switch(type.toLowerCase()) {
               case 'normal':
                     style = $('.select_normal option:selected').text();
                     break;
               case 'media':
                     style = $('.select_media option:selected').text();
                     break;
          }
    };
```

Currently when this code runs it prints the whole function out in my console logging.  Am I missing something here?   I know there are neater ways of assigning the variable but this is just pure curiosity! :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

This is an immediately executed anonymous function and its return value will be assigned to your variable. Maybe you want that?

```
var type  = $('#select_type option:selected').text(),
style = (function() {
   switch(type.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'normal':
         return $('.select_normal option:selected').text();
         break;
      case 'media':
         return $('.select_media option:selected').text();
         break;
      }
})();
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted, looks like I missed a couple of brackets ;) - Thanks alot :)